# Does the lexical path get slower with more entries

Tags: psycholinguistics, lexicon, readability, lexical

The lexical path of the dual-route hypothesis of reading states that people recognize whole words from memory. Does this theory assume the search time becomes greater with more words in the lexicon?? Analogous to how a search algorithm increases it is execution time with more entries. The increase there depends on the time complexity. Hence, what is the assumed time complexity of the search in the lexical path.

Comment: Psycholinguistic research reveals that the time increases logarithmically so with tens of thousands of word forms the increase is negligible and almost within statistical error.

Comment: Google's parallel architecture has almost no search time. It's blazing fast!

Comment: A great deal depends on what's being searched for and how the search space is indexed. Most search strategies are adapted for particular contexts and purposes, and raw size of the space is not often a criterion. Especially if it's well-indexed or -hashed.

Comment: @Atamiri. What does the tens of thousands of words stand for? A person's vocabullary?

Comment: Yes, the lexicon.

Comment: Do you recommend any specific piece of psycho-linguistic research. I read that an assumption of the lexical route is that  frequent words are more easily accessible.